# Calling function inside angular directive and inject event in parameters

Tags: function, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need your help.

I have a directive with a function parameter ( scope: { myParam: '@'}).  And I'm passing the parameters in HTML, like my-param="myFunc(param1, param2)"

This works perfectly.  But, I need to inject the event object in to the parameters.  Does some one know how can I do that?

I tried $provider.annotate and $provider.instantiate, but they did not work because it's taking the reference function in directive. ($a in my case), so it can't get the function arguments.

any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you're calling a function created by the & isolate scope syntax, you can pass parameters to it as a named map. If your directive is defined like this:

```
scope: { myParam: '&' },
link: function (scope, el) {
  el.on('click', function (e) {
    scope.myParam({$event: e});
  });
}
```

and used like this:

```
<my-directive my-param="console.log($event)"></my-directive>
```

... you should see the desired behavior.

Comment: Hi @chrisrhoden, in my case, I have a div with contenteditable, so, I created the parameter to substitute "enter" event when this parameter is defined

Answer (score 1):

chrisrhoden's answer is great. I would suggest to expand upon it a bit with the following. Doing so will help prevent ng-click double-firing issues relating to mobile devices and/or AngularJS conflicts with jQuery.

```
myApp.directive('responsiveClick', function(){
  return {
    scope: { myCb: '&' },
    link: function (scope, el,attr) {
  el.bind('touchstart click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    scope.myCb({$event: e});
  });
  }
}
});
```

along with the markup as follows:

```
<a class="mdi-navigation-cancel" my-cb="removeBasketItem($event,item)" responsive-click></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried passing it in the original function?

```
my-param="myFunc($event, param1, param2)"
```